# Inrush current limiting circuit and immediately turn OFF

Tags: mosfet-driver, current-limiting

I am using an inrush current limiting circuit with P-channel MOSFET:

[image]

My application needs to limit the inrush current but simultaneously I need to turn off the MOSFET immediately (< 1 ms) in a case of an overcurrent event. Now the MOSFET turns on and off about 20 ms till VOUT reaches VIN or GND.

How can I simply  modify the circuit to turn off the MOSFET immediately (< 1 ms)
but the turn on time should stay the same? I know a push-pull driver can do the trick but can not figure it out how to modify the circuit to make it work.

Comment: What are the values of all resistors and capacitors? What are the part numbers of the MOSFETs? What are the voltages of VIN and EN? How do you intend to measure the current?

Comment: As an FYI for readers wondering about its origin, the schematic in the question is from [On Semi AND9093/D - Using MOSFETs in Load Switch Applications](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND9093-D.PDF) (Figure 5).

Comment: So you turn the MOSFET off when current hits a trip value and current then falls to zero (below the trip level) so, what happens next? What do you want to happen next? Do you see that your question is under-constrained? Also the turn on time is dependent on the supply voltage so what do you really want to happen AND, in the process of applying a voltage to the input, if that voltage then disappears momentarily, what do you want to happen next?

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental flaw. When you apply VIN you will turn the switch on for ~ R2 * C1.  So this inrush limiter does not limit the inrush.

Answer (score 4):

I replaced R2 with a P-channel MOSFET Q3, which discharges the capacitor C1 quickly, improving the load switch cut-off time.

I assume you have a 3.3V or 5V digital enable signal, so I changed Q1's role into that of a driver for Q3's gate, to retain compatibility with such a signal. It has the unfortunate side effect of inverting the active level, so I've called it "INH", for inhibit, instead.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmvYzb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here are plots of the inhibit signal and the resulting output current:

[image]
[image]

#### Addendum #1

@tobalt made the aposite observation that neither the original circuit nor mine above mitigates inrush current in the case where Vin is applied while E/INH is intially is set to enable output. That's true, as shown here, where I hold INH low and step Vin:

[image]
[image]

He suggested a quick fix, with a capacitor across Q1. Here is my circuit modified in that way, with the resulting output current plot, working as @tobalt predicted:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2gGPa.png)</sup>

[image]

#### Addendum #2

As @tobalt also points out, if Q2's threshold Vgs is lower than that of Q3, Q2 can turn on when Vin lies between those two voltages, regardless of the state of the INH input and Q1. The situation can be modelled and demonstrated by removing Q1 and other unrelated parts, and holding Q3's gate at 0V (as if INH was asserted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmp5da.png)</sup>

Both gates are effectively at 0V until Q3 begins to conduct, and therefore one will switch on prior to the other. If the first to switch on is Q3, then there's no problem, Q2 will be inhibited throughout the rise of Vin. Otherwise there's a window of Vin during which Q2 can conduct even though INH is asserted.

Here I have chosen transistors where Q2's threshold voltage is lower than Q3's, and as the resulting plots show, Q2 begins to conduct long before Q3, before Q3 is able to pinch off its gate-source voltage:

[image]
[image]

The solution is either to choose MOSFETs where Q3's gate-source threshold voltage is significantly smaller than that of Q2, or, as @tobalt suggests, replace Q3 with a bipolar junction transistor, which will begin to conduct when Vin reaches 0.6V or so:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f73DFm.png)</sup>

I also replaced Q1 with a BJT, for the case where the INH signal is also derived from Vin, and would invoke the same problematic behavior.

The result is Q2's gate-source voltage being stifled as Vin reaches 600mV:

[image]

Comment: Add a cap in parallel with Q1 or it wont limit inrush currents (VIN step). The original circuit also does not stop inrush (see comment to OP), so this circuit is not worse in this regard :-)

Comment: @tobalt: Nice catch! I appended a section to my answer, to implement your suggestion.

Comment: Another issue is: Q3 needs lower threshold voltage than Q2 or again: the Q2 will erroneously turn on. your selection of parts luckily achieves this. Maybe this could be improved by using PNP instead of Q3.

Comment: @tobalt Can you please explain under what circumstances that problem might occur? I'm afraid I don't see it.

Comment: VIN step, INH doesnt matter. There is a small time when Q2 will be on, if its Vgsth is lower than that of Q3, namely while VIN is between the two thesholds. Depending on the size of CL this could be a problem..

Comment: I believe R2 has no function anymore with the BJT variant and can be omitted though. Sorry for the stepwise "nagging" :-( Up to you if you leave the individual updates in the answer. I think they actually show a rather realistic iterative design process though :-)

Comment: @tobalt I didn't want to remove R2 because without it, Q3 is always right on the edge of swtiching on. It's more a guard against Q1/C2 leakage. I see your point, but I feel that I've taken it as far as I want to. Thanks so much for your input though, I was really surprised how quickly you spotted the Vgs issue. Impressive, and humbling.

Comment: Thank you. You are right about R2, especially when the circuit gets hot, or when large R1 values are used for lower inrush current.

Answer (score 1):

T=RsC and I=CdV/dt +V/Rp for series switch R and load Rp , so you cannot achieve the same T by increasing Rs by duty cycle control at some frequency but you can limit the current by some duty factor.  Rs equiv = RdsOn/d.f. Averaged of time of pulses.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use push-pull in place of Q1, as you said.
2. The push-pull output goes to R1 & Q1 node.
3. Add a diode in parallel with R1, anode/A on Q1 side, cathod/K on R1 & R2 node.
4. Add a resistor in series with C1.
5. Show us your new circuitry, please.